# Javascript disable context menu on long press on anchor tag in iOS 8 safari

Tags: javascript, ios8, anchor, contextmenu

When I am holding long press on  anchor tag, it's giving context menu with options "open", "open in new tab", "add to reading list" and "copy". We are listening for "contextmenu" event but this event is not being fired.

As we know -webkit-touch-callout is broken in iOS 8.

Can somebody help us in disabling context menu in iOS 8 safari?
Thanks in advance.

Below is the code disable copy and contextmenu.

```
$("body").on("cut copy paste contextmenu dragstart", function () {
    return false;
});
```

we want make sure that users not copy anything. We have prevented copying text but There is a corner case, If image is inside the anchor tag, context menu gives option to open image in new tab and user can copy the image from new tab.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you should add even just a small bit of code, like your event listener. This will help answerers decipher your exact needs.

Comment: @NickDugger, Thanks for looking at the post. I have added code and detailed description on what we are trying achieve. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: For the record, preventing users from copy/pasting, or right-clicking is extremely irritating, and can frustrate your advanced users.

Comment: does css pointer events helps? http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: I agree that it will frustrate the users. But we have to force users not to copy/paste or right click in our application.

Comment: @NickDugger, I can not use pointer events because we also have functionality, clicking on the image we will enlarge the image. this will be broken if we use CSS pointer-events: none;